# Hey all can you help prove the following from Garson's ML for Philosophers:

Tags: modal-logic, deduction

Exercise 1.7 (e) Modal Logic For Philosophers 2nd edition:

[]p v []q/[](p v q) {hint: set-up vout first}

I would appreciate it if you can solve it using the methods laid out by Garson (PL+[]in+[]out); in other words, please don't solve it in an obscure manner which would be of no use to me [with all due respect].

Or, please verify the derivation I came up with:

[ ]p v [ ]q

|      |-[ ]

|      |        |-[ ]p

|      |        | p ([] out)

|      |        | p v q (v in)

|      |        |-[ ]q

|      |        | q ([] out)

|      |        | p v q (v in)

|      |        p v q (v out)

| [ ] (p v q)

the lines are there to distinguish subproofs, unfortunately I couldn't format it like Garson does in his book because SE has limited options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derivation is not legible to me; I've put down mine for you to compare. Simply MS Word with Cambria Math font may suffice for many short derivations.

[image: factoring out necessity operator from disjunction]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just had a question: my derivation is almost like yours, but instead of deriving the (v out) Iast my last derivation is the [  ]. That is, i put the box subproof, and then use the v out inside the  [  ] subproof. Do you think that should be fine?

Comment: Also, I edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @ryan that would be superfluous, because you would need boxed subproof again to pass from □p to p